# Bootstrap drop down disappears on input but tabbing works

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

On my site I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7, jquery-3.2.1.js and 3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

My Login box top right, which is in a drop down menu of Bootstrap goes away when I click on login inputs.

It stays in place when I alternate jquery and bootstrap js links in the header, but then the tabs doesnt work.

I have gone through tutorials here and all seem to point to add the below code, but it still doesnt work. Can somebody help me?

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/o3uhaxc3/)

```
$(function () {
// Fix input element click problem
$('.dropdown input').click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add, at least, a link to a  `JSFiddle` or a code snippet with an example code, instead of a link to your website.

Comment: It's a bit more difficult than that, I'm linking to Bootstrap and Jquery cdn and the menu is in aspx site.master.

Comment: [JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/o3uhaxc3/)

- Doesnt seem to work at all in fiddle, but at least it's got most of the code

Comment: Thanks but, can you add it to the question, pls ?

Comment: It seems that the JS code on the fiddle is truncated.